# How to remove default space form console of printing number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uri

I am trying to solve online judge problems with JavaScript. I am facing a problem. When I am printing a number it is generating a space. But I don't want the space. Actually the online judge is not wanted the space.

Problem link: [URI 1002](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1002)

My JavaScript Code:

```
var R = parseFloat(readline());
var A = 3.14159 * (R * R);
console.log("A=", A.toFixed(4));
```

Here I am giving screenshots.

My output:

[image]

Here is space after the `=` sign.

Judge output:

[image]

Comment: `.log("A=", A.toFixed(4));` prints to distinct values, which will always be separated by some whitespace character. If you don't want that, log only one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're passing the 2 variables to `console.log` separately, separated with a comma.

Concatenate the string you're passing to the `console`:

```
console.log("A=" + A.toFixed(4));
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 1):

@Cerbrus Answered your question

Another alternative would be to use template strings
Instead of using the plus operator for concatenation do this:

```
console.log(`A=${A.toFixed(4)}`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Your answer is really helpful.